# MySQL - Insert statement fails when entering into a table with only foreign keys

Tags: mysql, syntax

So my table looks like this (from the `"Show Create Table <table>"` query) :

```
CREATE TABLE stars_in_movies(
star_id int NOT NULL,
movie_id int NOT NULL,
KEY 'star_id' ('star_id'),
KEY 'movie_id' ('movie_id'),
CONSTRAINT 'stars_in_movies_ibfk_1' FOREIGN KEY('star_id') REFERENCES 'stars'('id'),
CONSTRAINT 'stars_in_movies_ibfk_2' FOREIGN KEY('movie_id') REFERENCES 'movies'('id'),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

And I am trying to simply enter a new entry into this table as so:

```
INSERT INTO stars_in_movies (907010, 834410);
```

And I get an Error as follows:

```
ERROR 1064 (4200): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to user near '907010, 834410)' at line 1
```

Now I know that this error is just simply a syntax error, but why am I receiving the error for such a simple INSERT query? Everywhere online suggest that this would be a valid statement, especially if the two entry fields are ACTUAL ids from the other two referenced tables.

EDIT:

Okay so for this trivial example I was simply missing the `VALUES` keyword. To add onto the question, how come this query returns the same error?

```
INSERT INTO stars_in_movies
VALUES
(693109, m.id)
SELECT m.id
FROM movies m
WHERE m.title='Inception';
```

Comment: Re: EDIT, you can't combine `INSERT ... VALUES` and `INSERT ... SELECT`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO stars_in_movies values (907010, 834410);
```

You are missing the keyword `values`.

**[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3bb07)**

**EDIT:**

After you comment, you also have one more option to insert into the table like this

```
INSERT INTO stars_in_movies 
select 907010, 834410;
```

**EDIT:**

This query wont work

```
INSERT INTO stars_in_movies
VALUES
(693109, m.id)
SELECT m.id
FROM movies m
WHERE m.title='Inception';
```

You need to specify the particular value in the `VALUES`. In

```
INSERT INTO stars_in_movies
    VALUES
    (693109, m.id)
```

m.id is not defined and hence it is unknown to the analyzer. So you are getting the error.

You are probably looking for this:

```
INSERT INTO stars_in_movies
SELECT 693109, m.id
FROM movies m
WHERE m.title='Inception';
```

Comment: YES! thank you so much rahul, that last example is perfect! Thank you so much again, especially for the explanation as to why it wasn't working.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like you are missing the **`VALUES`** keyword.

```
INSERT INTO stars_in_movies (star_id, movie_id) VALUES (907010, 834410)
                                                ^^^^^^
```

Comment: Okay that was incredibly trivial, then how come this question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5391344/insert-with-select) suggest I can get away with the INSERT without the VALUES keyword?

Comment: @LeoVannini:- Correct me if I am wrong but how is that [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/591222/cannot-connect-to-sql-server-remotely-or-locally-after-reboot/591344#591344) linked to this one?

Comment: @RahulTripathi I apologize, wrong [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5391344/insert-with-select)

Comment: @LeoVannini:- Yes that is differnt. If you are using select statement to add  values then you dont have to add VALUES keyword.

Comment: @RahulTripathi can you check the recent edit and explain then why my query, following the linked page's format, is throwing a syntax error as well?

Comment: @LeoVannini:- Tried to explain that in my answer. Please check!